# Drawing in Java Swing with RGBA

Tags: java, swing, colors, rgba

How can I draw in swing using RGBA (colors with transparency)? The only class I found is Color which is sRGB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Color will understand alpha and even has constructors that accept it: [Color API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

Are you drawing in a BufferedImage?

Comment: @HFOE: "Color will understand alpha and even has constructors that accept it."  Specifically [Color(r,g,b,a)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). "Are you drawing in a BufferedImage?"  If so, be sure to use one of the types that specifies an alpha component, such as [BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB).